# Accessing Azure Key Vault with User Assigned Managed Identity in AKS for Java Web Application

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

When we try to access Azure Key Vault from Managed Identity enabled AKS Cluster we see the below error:
**ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient - MSI: Failed to acquire tokens after retrying 3 times
[reactor-http-epoll-1] ERROR com.azure.identity.ManagedIdentityCredential - Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call for scopes [https://vault.azure.net/.default]: MSI: Failed to acquire tokens after retrying 3 times**

**Steps for setup**
We are using Sample Hello World App to test this Scenario. The war is deployed into AKS using Azure Devops CI/CD

1.Created a Cluster in Kubernetes Service
2.Created User Assigned Managed Identity using Managed Identity service of Azure
3.Added this Managed Identity to VMSS of My Cluster under Identity Section
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L9Wv.png)

4.Created a Key Vault and assigned my managed Identity as Access Policy with set,get,list,delete Enabled
5.Included below API to authenticate the Key Vault Access in my Code

```
ManagedIdentityCredential managedIdentityCredential = new  ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder().clientId(clientId).build();
        
             
           SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder() .vaultUrl(vaultBase)
              .credential(managedIdentityCredential) .buildClient();
KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.setSecret("DEV", "New_Var_In_Dev");
                  System.out.printf("Secret created with name \"%s\" and value \"%s\"%n",
                  secret.getName(), secret.getValue()); //createManagedIdentityCredential();
                                 
               
                  KeyVaultSecret secret1 = secretClient.getSecret("DEV");
                  System.out.printf("Retrieved secret with name \"%s\" and value \"%s\"%n",
                  secret1.getName(), secret1.getValue());
```

Comment: it looks like you do not use your created object `ManagedIdentityCredential managedIdentityCredential`?!

Comment: probably need to stick it in here: Instead of `.credential(defaultCredential)` try `.credential(managedIdentityCredential )`

Comment: we have used that also but error is same

Comment: sounds like something else is wrong. go `kubectl exec` into your pods and try to manually call the token endpoint to see if that even works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-curl

Comment: tryig to do that but getting below error. can u help us outroot@web-app-764df48fc5-6ppxh:/usr/local/tomcat# curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F' -H Metadata:true -s
getting assigned identities for pod pocns/web-app-764df48fc5-6ppxh in CREATED state failed after 16 attempts, retry duration [5]s, error: <nil>. Check MIC pod logs foridentity assignment errors

Comment: are you using pod identity?! you did not mention that

Comment: No. Is pod identity enabled by default

Comment: no, but your logs suggest there is something going on

Comment: Yeah you do need pod identity to make your application works with managed identity